# Algunas operaciones de una función no se hacen cuando instancio un nuevo objeto en tkinter

Tags: python, poo, tkinter, clase

En este video podrás ver el código completo y sus funciones: https://youtu.be/oI3j51iRmjg Lo que pasa, es que cuando le doy al botón de "Nuevo" se instancia un nuevo objeto de la clase Aplication donde después creará un objeto de la clase Stadistic_table, el problema es que al oprimir el botón "Operar!" deberían hacerse las operaciones, pero en cambio no pasa nada. Aquí va la parte del código.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import Intervales
import webbrowser

class errors:
    def __init__(self, type_error):
        self.error = type_error
    def sort_out_error(self):
        if self.error == 'selection_error':
            self.error = 'Error de selección'
        if self.error == 'create_file_error':
            self.error = 'Error de tabla'
        if self.error == 'amount_error':
            self.error = 'Cantidad de filas invalida'
        return self.error    

class menu():
    def __init__(self, place):
        self.place = place
        # Main menu
        self.main_menu = Menu(self.place)
        self.file_menu = Menu(self.main_menu, tearoff = 0)
        self.edit_menu = Menu(self.main_menu, tearoff = 0)
        self.help_menu = Menu(self.main_menu, tearoff = 0)
   
        self.file_menu.add_command(label = 'Nuevo', command = self.program_new)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label = 'Guardar')
        self.file_menu.add_separator()
        self.file_menu.add_command(label = 'Cerrar', command = self.place.destroy)
        self.file_menu.add_separator()
        self.file_menu.add_command(label = 'Salir', command = exit)
        
        self.edit_menu.add_command(label = 'Cortar')
        self.edit_menu.add_command(label = 'Copiar')
        self.edit_menu.add_command(label = 'Pegar')
        self.edit_menu.add_separator()
        self.edit_menu.add_command(label = 'Moda')
        self.edit_menu.add_command(label = 'Mediana')
        self.edit_menu.add_command(label = 'Media aritmetica')
        
        self.help_menu.add_command(label = 'Bienvenido', command = self.help_window)
        self.help_menu.add_separator()
        self.help_menu.add_command(label = 'Como se usa', command = self.help_window)
        self.help_menu.add_command(label = 'Redes sociales', command = self.execute_web)
        self.help_menu.add_separator()
        self.help_menu.add_command(label = 'Acerca de...', command = self.help_window)
        self.help_menu.add_command(label = 'Licencia', command = self.help_window)
        # Cascades
        self.main_menu.add_cascade(label = 'Archivo', menu = self.file_menu)
        self.main_menu.add_cascade(label = 'Editar', menu = self.edit_menu)
        self.main_menu.add_cascade(label = 'Ayuda', menu = self.help_menu)
        place['menu'] = self.main_menu 

    # MENU OPTIONS/FILE
    # Create a new program using recursion
```

justo en este pedazo de codigo es cuando se crea una nueva ventana del programa, instancia un nuevo objeto de la clase 'aplication' y por ende debería hacer todas las operaciones que se solicitan después. el problema es que si trabajo con la tabla nueva, al momento de operar en cualquier tipo de tabla, las operaciones matematicas no funcionan

```
    def program_new(self): 
        self.new = Tk()
        self.new_app = aplication(self.new)
        self.new.mainloop()

    # MENU OPTIONS/HELP
    def help_window(self):
        self.help_wind = Toplevel(self.main_wind)
        self.help_wind.title('Help')
        self.help_wind.geometry('320x415')
        self.help_wind.resizable(0,0)
        # Help label frame
        self.help_label_frame = LabelFrame(self.help_wind, text = 'Ayuda')
        self.help_label_frame.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5)
        # Content 
        Label(self.help_label_frame, text = 'Bienvenido:', justify = LEFT).grid(row = 0, columnspan = 15, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Message(self.help_label_frame, width = 300,text = (
            'Este programa te será útil para crear tablas estadisticas en cuestión de segundos, solamente debes tener los conceptos claros '
        )).grid(row = 1)
        Label(self.help_label_frame, text = 'Como se usa:', justify = LEFT).grid(row = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Message(self.help_label_frame, width = 300, text = (
            'Iniclamente selecciona una de las opciones de tabla (Que clase de datos manejas, y de que forma los vas a ingresar). Luego ingresa los datos de la forma en como escogiste'
        )).grid(row = 3)
        Label(self.help_label_frame, text = 'Acerca de:', justify = LEFT).grid(row = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Message(self.help_label_frame, width = 300, justify = LEFT, text = (
            'Programa desarollado en Python importing Tkinter libraries')).grid(row = 5, column = 0)
        Label(self.help_label_frame, text = 'Licencia:', justify = LEFT).grid(row = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Message(self.help_label_frame, width = 300, justify = LEFT, text = (
            'La distribucionn de este programa debe ser concedida bajo la autorización del desarollador'
        )).grid(row = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Label(self.help_label_frame, justify = LEFT, text = 'CORREO DE CONTACTO ').grid(row = 8, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        Entry(self.help_label_frame, state = 'readonly', textvariable = StringVar(value = 'expresspiano57@gmail.com')).grid(row = 9, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    # Open page web        
    def execute_web(self):
        webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC120Xrak1Ccx32K12nElL7w')  



class stadistic_table():
    def __init__(self, place, icon, __row, __type, labels):
        self.columns = labels
        self.type_table = __type
        # Stadistic table Toplevel
        self.table_wind = Toplevel(place)
        self.table_wind.title('Tabla estadistica')
        self.table_wind.iconbitmap(icon)
        self.table_wind.resizable(0,0)
        # Menu
        self.manu_table = menu(self.table_wind)
        # Frame table
        self.frame_table = LabelFrame(self.table_wind, text = 'Tabla')
        self.frame_table.grid(padx = 10, pady = 5) 
        # Message label
        self.message_label = Label(self.table_wind, text = 'Rellena los campos escenciales', foreground = 'red', justify = CENTER)
        self.message_label.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W+E, padx = 3, pady = 3)

        # Labels
        for label in range(len(labels)):
            Label(self.frame_table, relief = RIDGE, text = labels[label]).grid(row = 0, column = label, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = W+E)
        # Stadistic lists and entries
        self.columns_entry_list = [[None for column in range(len(self.columns))] for row in range(__row)]
        for row in range(len(self.columns_entry_list)):
            for column in range(len(self.columns_entry_list[row])):
                if column >= 2:
                    write_space = Entry(self.frame_table, state = 'readonly')
                else:
                    write_space = Entry(self.frame_table)  
                write_space.grid(row = row+1, column = column, padx = 3, pady = 2)
                self.columns_entry_list[row][column] = write_space
                
        # Sumatory list of every column
        self.sumatories_list = []
        counter = int()
        for entry_sumatory in range(len(labels)):
            print('loop')
            if entry_sumatory == 0:
                value = '∑'
            else:
                value = '...'
            self.entry_sumatory = Entry(self.frame_table, state = 'readonly', textvariable = StringVar(value = value))
            self.entry_sumatory.grid(row = __row+1, column = counter)
            self.sumatories_list.append(self.entry_sumatory)
            counter += 1

        # Updating and saving button
        Button(self.table_wind, relief = GROOVE, text = 'Operar!', command = self.update_content).grid(row = 2, sticky = W+E, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    # =========================
    # Show content on the table     
    def show_content(self, row, column, __content):
        self.columns_entry_list[row][column]['textvariable'] = StringVar(value = __content)
    # =========================

    # Average of intervales
    def average_intervales(self, index):      
        __average = Intervales.average(self.columns_entry_list[index][0].get())
        # print(f'Average of {self.columns_entry_list[index][0].get()} equals to: {__average}')
        self.show_content(index, 3, __average)     
    # Intervales validation
    def validating_intervales(self):
        for row in range(len(self.columns_entry_list)):
            validation = Intervales.val_inter(self.columns_entry_list[row][0].get())
            if validation == True:
                self.average_intervales(row)

    # Fi/fi operations
    def fi_columns(self):
        # Sumatory (fi/Fi)
        sumatory = int()
        for row in range(len(self.columns_entry_list)):
            try:      
                sumatory += int(self.columns_entry_list[row][1].get())
                self.show_content(row, 2, sumatory)
            except:
                pass  
        self.sumatories_list[1]['textvariable'] = StringVar(value = sumatory)

    def fi_xi_multiply(self):
        sumatory = float()
        for row in range(len(self.columns_entry_list)):
            try:
                # fi * xi
                result = float(self.columns_entry_list[row][self.columns.index('xi')].get()) * float(self.columns_entry_list[row][self.columns.index('fi')].get())
                sumatory += result
                self.show_content(row, self.columns.index('fi * xi'), result)        
            except:
                pass

        self.sumatories_list[self.columns.index('fi * xi')]['textvariable'] = StringVar(value = sumatory)
   

    # Calling every function to fill the spaces
    def update_content(self):
        print('c')
        if self.type_table == 'Cuantitativo continuo':
            # Intervales
            self.validating_intervales()
            # Fi column  
            self.fi_columns()    
            # fi * xi column
            self.fi_xi_multiply()
                  
        elif self.type_table == 'Cuantitativo discreto':  
            self.fi_columns()    
            self.fi_xi_multiply()

        elif self.type_table == 'Cualitativos':
            self.fi_columns()    

        # To validate if there's spaces witouth content
        self.validating_spaces()

    # Final validation about spaces in table
    def validating_spaces(self):
        for row in range(len(self.columns_entry_list)):
            for column in range(len(self.columns_entry_list[row])):
                if self.columns_entry_list[row][column].get() == '':
                    self.message_label['text'] = 'Rellena todos los espacios'
                    return
                else:
                    self.message_label['text'] = 'Tabla generada exitosamente'



class aplication():
    def __init__(self, window):
        
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('Stadistic creators')
        self.wind.resizable(0,0)
        self.ico = r'C:\Users\JESUS DAVID PEREZ\Documents\PROYECTOS EN PYTHON\GrandesProyectos.py\StadisticsApp\Icon.ico'
        self.wind.iconbitmap(self.ico)

        # Main frame
        self.main = LabelFrame(self.wind, text='Selecciona una opción')
        self.main.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 5, padx = 5)
        # Main menu
        self.menu_main = menu(self.wind)
        # Table in a tree view
        self.select_table = ttk.Treeview(self.main, height = 6)
        self.select_table.heading('#0' ,text = 'Tipos de datos')
        self.select_table.insert('', 0, text = 'Cuantitativo continuo')
        self.select_table.insert('', 0, text = 'Cuantitativo discreto')
        self.select_table.insert('', 0, text = 'Cualitativos')
        self.select_table.grid()
        # Rows entry
        Label(self.wind, text = ' Cantidad de filas de la tabla: ', relief = RIDGE, width = 25).grid(row = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.rows_entry = Entry(self.wind)
        self.rows_entry.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        # Select class button
        Button(self.wind, text = 'Crear tabla', relief = GROOVE, command = self.create_table).grid(row = 3, sticky = W + E, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        # Message updater
        self.message_screen = Label(self.wind, text = 'Selecciona una opción', foreground = 'red')
        self.message_screen.grid(row = 4, sticky = W + E)


        
    # Selecting validation
    def validate_selection(self, selection, label, conditions):
        tries = int()
        lenght_conditions = len(conditions)
        print()
        for condition in conditions:   
            tries += 1        
            if selection == condition and self.rows_entry.get() != '':             
                print(f'* ({condition}) * Has been found succesfully! in try number {tries}')  
                returning = str(condition)
                break
            else:
                content_message = errors('selection_error')
                label['text'] = content_message.sort_out_error()  
                print(content_message.sort_out_error(), f'* ({content_message}) * | Try number {tries} of {lenght_conditions}')  
                returning = 'error' # There's any error                
        return returning

    # Create the stadistic table, last step to create the stadistic table
    def create_table(self):
        # Amount rows for the table must be > 3 to be normal
        try:
            if int(self.rows_entry.get()) <= 3 or int(self.rows_entry.get()) >= 15 :
                content_message = errors('amount_error')
                self.message_screen['text'] = content_message.sort_out_error()
                return
        except:
            content_message = errors('selection_error')
            self.message_screen['text'] = content_message.sort_out_error()
            return
        # Validating selection 
        selection = (self.select_table.item(self.select_table.selection())['text'])
        type_data_tuple = ('Cuantitativo continuo', 'Cuantitativo discreto', 'Cualitativos')
        if self.validate_selection(selection, self.message_screen, type_data_tuple) == 'error':
            return   
        elif self.validate_selection(selection, self.message_screen, type_data_tuple) == 'Cualitativos':
            print('\n* Cualitativo * has been instancied as table')
            self.final_table = stadistic_table(self.wind, self.ico, int(self.rows_entry.get()), selection, (' Caracteristica ','fi','Fi'))
        elif self.validate_selection(selection, self.message_screen, type_data_tuple) == 'Cuantitativo continuo':
            print('\n* Cuantitativo * has been instancied as table')
            self.final_table = stadistic_table(self.wind, self.ico, int(self.rows_entry.get()), selection, (' Intervalos ','fi','Fi','xi','fi * xi'))
        elif self.validate_selection(selection, self.message_screen, type_data_tuple) == 'Cuantitativo discreto':
            print('\n* Cuantitativo * has been instancied as table')
            self.final_table = stadistic_table(self.wind, self.ico, int(self.rows_entry.get()), selection,('xi','fi','Fi','fi * xi'))
        self.message_screen['text'] = 'Tabla generada exitosamente'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    app = aplication(window)

    window.mainloop()
```